# Xamarin Forms, setting BarBackgroundColor NavigationPage in prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When using Prism 7+ as navigation framework in Xamarin Forms.

What would be most elegant way for changing the BarBackgroundColor of navigation page?

i Prism 6, there was a way for customizing navigation page using INavigationPageProvider , but that is no longer an option..

Ideally being able to change the color via binding to view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prism 7+ you can register you own custom NavigationPage using the usual `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MyNavigationPage>();`

Your NavigationPage needs to be inherited from `Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage`.

Of course you can set the backgroundcolor, bind to a ViewModel etc... 
I'm adding ToolbarItems I need on all my other pages here.

Your first Navigation Action should look like this `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(MyNavigationPage)}/{nameof(MyFirstPage)}");`

Comment: yep, I've figured custom navigation page may be a way to go... but how to control the color based on the child page or viewmodel?... example: NavigationPage/FirstPage ... background should be Red, but if users navigates from FirstPage to Second Page... the color should get changed to Green... here the instance of navigationPage used would still be the same...

Comment: Also a NavigationPage can have a ViewModel. As your application will have (in most cases) only one Instances of the NavigationPage you than need to find a way to change the properties in the NavigationPageViewModel. 

To do this, I created a NavigationHandlerService, which I registered as Singelton. The NavigationPage binds to properties of this Service and my other ViewModels use the Service to make changes to my NavigationPage.

Another way to go could be the "MessagingCenter" and send change messages in your other ViewModels